# How to wait for page to load completely using JavaScript in Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying get for page to load completely before doing an action. I don't want to start an action while loading circle on the browser tab is still turning. My wait for ajax function is not working for some cases, especially for new page loading. My function is JQuery based:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
boolean stillRunningAjax = (Boolean) jsDriver
        .executeScript("return window.jQuery != undefined && jQuery.active != 0");
return !stillRunningAjax;
```

if that comes false, running it again.

But for page loading, after it returns true, browser is still loading (loading circle is turning) for a couple of seconds more (sometimes much more).

I've tried implicitlyWait but it stops the function at the same time with my function.

Some says there is not a complete solution for this in selenium. But there should be. Maybe a JavaScript included solution, anything.

Comment: Sounds like your "page readiness" depends on other things than just jQuery's internal active state. You should talk to the developers of the page, but I'd suggest an approach of (perhaps) waiting until the loading spinner is gone *after* the above turns true.

Comment: java AND javascript tagged?

Comment: @Kayvar Yes, why?

Comment: @TaylanDerinbay Thought that was a mistake... I guess even if it is written in Java there is some jquery so nevermind..

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript to wait for page to load:

```
void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
}
```

If you're waiting for an ajax to display an element on page, you can wait for the element itself.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
 .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Comment: why C#?  this is tagged [java]

Comment: The OP is clear that the issue is waiting for Ajax requests to complete. Ajax requests have no influence on `document.readyState`, so it is pointless to check the value of `document.readyState`.

Comment: Then waiting for the dynamic element is the easiest approach in my opinion. If he wants to wait for a page without ajax, then first code sample will do the trick. made that bit more clear in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: About the waiting the element, the elements I need were already loaded and seeing in the page in most cases. But if I make an action with them without waiting page to load, it gives errors in some cases, that's why I need to wait until the page is loaded completely.

Comment: @ingrid.e By the way your code block gives the same result as mine. It finishes before the completion of page load. Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you provide more information / more details about the elements on the page and what is your goal? also, what browser.

Comment: I have the same issue, namely Selenium clicks on an element before the Javascript listener for that element was loaded. Still no solution...